# Creating an SEO friendly URL with Htaccess File

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I am trying to setup an SEO friendly redirect, but need to be using my .htaccess in a specific way.  Here is what my URLs look like right now:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/report/index.php?id=38678a80dfea5924
```

I need to change the URLs so that they look like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/report/38678a80dfea5924
```

I've read several tutorials about creating SEO friendly URLs, but most of them are referring to making changes to the .htaccess at the root of the domain.  Is there any way to do this but only edit the .htaccess file that's in my `reports` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've changed all of your links so that they look like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/report/38678a80dfea5924
```

Then in the htaccess file inside the "report" folder, you just need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```